# Comma or no comma for phrase

Tags: commas

If I am wishing Walter a Happy Retirement should I write Happy Retirement Walter or Happy Retirement, Walter

Comment: Which do you think it should be?

Comment: I wonder how many people include a comma in their first ***Hello, world*** program.

Comment: Some would require \, I suspect.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Present company excepted, I bet the average age of the "some" who *would* require the comma is more that the average age of those who wouldn't. I believe over many decades there's been a slow but steady decrease in the use of commas (partially offset by a reduction in the use of *full stops*, some of which now get "demoted" to commas).

Comment: Punctuation is always a flurry of almost-works.